# Fix the order of auto_incremented keys mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which has a primary key book_num which is being auto_incremented, problem is that I had deleted some books from it and then inserted more books and so through an interface, so if the book with book_num = 4 was deleted now the table is missing book_num 4. so it would be like 1, 2, 3 and then 5 how can i make it so that missing spot just get covered like since there are 4 rows with column book_num 1, 2, 3, 4, not skipping the 4 like 1, 2, 3, 5. I can duplicate a table just like the original one and then insert all values from that table to the new table so there no skipping like that but I was wondering if there is a MySQL command to do that. Here is the actual table which is missing the number 79 because I deleted that book.

`+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| book_num | book_name                                                |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|       74 | MySQL Cookbook                                           |
|       75 | PHP Cookbook                                             |
|       76 | Learn to Program with Python                             |
|       77 | THE MIT ENCYCLOPEDIA OF THE COGNITIVE SCIENCES           |
|       78 | Microsoft Visual C++/CLI Step by Step                    |
|       80 | Advanced Problems in Core Mathematics                    |
|       81 | The C+ + Programming Language                            |
|       82 | Design Patterns : Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented S |
|       83 | Developing Concepts in Applied Intelligence              |`

You see the 79 is missing is there a way to push all the indexes after 78 up there by filling the gap of 79. so like after 78 it shows:

`|     79 | Advanced Problems in Core Mathematics                    |`
and so forth.

Comment: Hi, answer depends upon how frequent and quantity of deletion/insertion is. In my opinion you should never hard delete(remove it from the database), always keep a flag to signify it the record is deleted or not, its called soft deleting. As for your question, MySql table actually keeps an auto_increment counter and assign next possible value to your inserted row. AFAIK you cannot directly get the available number from mysql, either you somehow maintain it and  while inserting provide the book_id yourself. Or if your deletion insertions are very low, do as you suggested (i wont recomment this).

Comment: Generally a bad idea. Do you have a another table that references book_num? Auto_increment numbers are for machine readability and can have gaps for a number of reasons.

Comment: @danblack yeah one more table I know that if I change the order here it would impact other tables connected to this, I have already considered that.

Comment: Ah, good. Still don't do it.